# Installing pyodbc for Python 3.3 on windows (can't use pip)?

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, python-3.3

I'm trying to connect to the Microsoft SQL server.
I'm using python code to do so, and I want to download pyodbc.
I go to the Python33 directory by doing this: cd C:\Python33\, and I try typing in pip install pyodbc, but it doesn't recognize pip.

Did anyone else have this problem with Python 3.3?

I'm also trying to do this:
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install pyodbc

But it says: "The system cannot find the path specified."

Answer (score 1):

Pip is a stand-alone tool, you will have to install that as well in 3.3. Here is a link on a really good explanation:

([How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows))

In 3.4, pip was included, but you will have to call it with

```
python -m pip
```

inside your scripts directory

Comment: I would also recommend getting a newer version of Python than 3.3, which is five years old at this point; having `pip` installed with Python alone is worth the hassle!